# VBA with solver embedded only works for first active cell reference

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I would like to create a macro to enable me to select an active cell("Q50") which will generate solver by minimising value in activecell by changing cells `$M$2,$M$3,$M$5,$M$7` subject to `$M$2>=0 and $M$3>=0`. Every thing with the code works fine for the first selected activecell. However when I click the subsequent cell down the row `("Q51")`, the code doesn't work for the solver anymore. Kindly help. I am a beginner in VBA. See below for code.

```
  Sub JCCMacro()
' JCCMacro Macro

'Save ActiveCell Reference for future use
Dim PrevCell As Range
Set PrevCell = ActiveCell

'Solver Code
    SolverOk SetCell:="PrevCell.Select", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:= _
        "$M$2,$M$3,$M$5,$M$7"
   SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    'Copy in sample and out of sample error
    PrevCell.Resize(1, 3).Copy

    'Paste Values of in sample and out of sample errors
    PrevCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Copy Co-efficient
    Range("M2:M7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    'Select paste destination
    PrevCell.Offset(0, 7).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

    'Copy Paste Following months data
    PrevCell.Offset(1, -1).Resize(12, 1).Copy

    'Select target destination
    PrevCell.Offset(0, 13).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
PrevCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to avoid using `Select` and `ActiveCell` in your code. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179) for an explanation. You might need to start the macro by grabbing the `Selection` if you want the user to select the "question" and then run the macro.

Comment: So every time you want Solver to keep using cells $M$2,$M$3,$M$5,$M$7 subject to $M$2>=0 and $M$3>=0 but to write the answer to the cell selected by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
Sub JCCMacro()
' JCCMacro Macro

'Save ActiveCell Reference for future use
Dim targetCell As Range

    Set targetCell = ActiveCell

'Solver Code
    SolverOk SetCell:=targetCell.Address, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:= _
        "$M$2,$M$3,$M$5,$M$7", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
   ' Your code didn't show anything that set these constraints
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$M$3", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"""
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$M$2", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"""

    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    'Copy in sample and out of sample error
    targetCell.Resize(RowSize:=1, ColumnSize:=3).Copy

    'Paste Values of in sample and out of sample errors
    targetCell.Offset(RowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Copy Co-efficient
    targetCell.Parent.Range("M2:M7").Copy

    'Select paste destination
    targetCell.Offset(RowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Copy Paste Following months data
    targetCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=-1).Resize(RowSize:=12, ColumnSize:=1).Copy

    'Select target destination
    targetCell.Offset(RowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=13).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

    targetCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=0).Select
End Sub
```

If you want solver to use different variable or constraint cells, you will need to change the cell addresses shown in the code. Or define a `Range` variable which you then change to point to the new cells, using the `Offset` method maybe, and in the solver code use `rangeVariable.Address` instead of `$m$2`.